# Forwarding from One Email to Case Address to Another

Tags: apex, email2case

We have a number of email to case addresses, sometimes customers will send to the incorrect address so our users want to be able to forward to the another address. However, doing this maintains the thread and so the email just gets attached to the original case rather than creating a new case for the correct queue.

One thought I had was that if I could determine if it was forwarded I could strip the thread from email body. Is there any way of determining if an email has been forwarded (from within SF). If not any other ideas?

Comment: It seems like there "ought" to be a way to create workflow that reassign it to a different email queue, but I do understand that it's saved as an email object with that email address on it. That would seem to limit you to creating a class that would somehow edit the inbound email address on the record then reassign it to the different case queue. Not an easy or "pretty" solution.